# Thread 1 Breakpoint 3.1, unsure if issue with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I never have had any issues with building my test build until today, where suddenly it stops while starting up as a test app and the error pops up saying Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1.

This is then proceeded with the following code being displayed and highlighted

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignUpViewController.keyboardWillChangeFrame(_:)), name: "UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification", object: nil)
```

Within the debug window, it displays the following error

```
[Error]: invalid login parameters (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0)
(lldb)
```

Im unsure why this has happened suddenly either, I wasn't changing any code when this suddenly happened.

Comment: OP, if I'm wrong with this diagnose, please leave a comment here and we'll help further.

Comment: That does answer it; I appreciate the link to the existing question and will in future put more effort into finding an answer for something small like this as I'm sure others would have encountered similar.

Also appreciate @pacholik for editing my question with the correct formatting; will make sure not to overlook in the future also